# class composition and header problems

Tags: c++

Currently, I'm writing a project for fun and faced next problem.Let's suppose I'm creating `class Bank` and I want to define classes `LoginController` and `Departure`

```
class Bank{
    class LoginController{
       //some implemantation 
    }
    class Departure{
       //some departure 
    }
}
```

To avoid making huge declaration of `Bank` inside `Bank.h` I want to define them in separate files

```
//Bank.h
#include "LoginController.h"
#include "Departure"
class Bank{
  class LoginController;
  class Departure;
  LoginController controller;  
  Departure departure;
  ...
}
//LoginController.h
class Bank; //forward declaration
class Bank::LoginController{
   bool getAccess(Bank::Departure);
}
//Departure.h
//Departure depends on Bank class aswell
class Bank; //forward declartion
class Bank::Departure{...}
```

This code wont compile with huge stack trace.It can be solved with one big `Bank.cpp` and writing it all there, however, i don't want to make one huge file.
I assume this is a bad design problem, however, i'm still interested if it possible to implement this class as I wanted.Even if I define `LoginController && Departure` structure inside `Bank` i want separate cpp files for each class, however, header guard will close access to it after including it to one of cpp files.The best solution i can see is defining all in one header but not inside each other.

And one more question.Is it possible to define 1 header file with all includes like

```
#ifndef HeaderFile
#define HeaderFile
  #include <iostream>
  #include <memory>
  ....
#endif
```

From the previous question, i understand that this will open only for one file, therefore do we need to provide each file with needed headers. Including the same header to different files seems expensive.

Comment: Why the need to declare the classes inside Bank? Just declare each class in each header.

Comment: In order for you to hold a member of type `Departure` inside of `Bank`, the compiler must have a full definition of `Departure` available (in order to know the size of memory required to allocate a `Bank`.

Comment: "And one more question.Is it possible to define 1 header file with all includes like" Yes but don't, it will murder compile time and lead to all kinds of unexpected symbols popping up as defined in new .cpp files that only include the header that has a bunch of other inclusions.

Comment: "Is it possible to define 1 header file with all includes[?]" Yes, but this is generally a bad idea. It greatly increases the amount of stuff that needs to be compiled, blurs what resources are actually used by your program, and may lead to naming collisions between your code and stuff you included but aren't using.

Comment: Although not sure, a reason why this class Bank::LoginController is not working in another header, is because the class LoginController  is defined privately inside Bank. Maybe adding public: before solves this

Comment: *Even if I define LoginController && Departure structure inside Bank i want separate cpp files for each class, however, header guard will close access to it after including it to one of cpp files.*  This is incorrect; the include guards only prevent multiple definition within a single translation unit (i.e. a single `cpp` file).  One header with 3 cpp files will work just fine.

Comment: You can't separate out declarations in the way you're describing, and tbh it seems like a pointless exercise. If you really want them in separate files, and not have the inner classes pollute any outside namespace, then just put them in their own namespace instead of nesting them in a class :).

Answer (score 2):

You can put the `#include` directives inside the `Bank` class.

`Bank.h`

```
class Bank {
    #include "LoginController.h"
    #include "Departure.h"
    // Bank implementation
}
```

`LoginController.h`

```
class LoginController {
    // some implementation
}
```

`Departure.h`

```
class Departure {
    // some implementation
}
```

Comment: Horrifying but effective.